# How to disable CSRF token for specific endpoints(URLs) with Ring in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, csrf, compojure, ring, liberator

I have a web app which has `CSRF` protection but I need to disable this protection for some `endpoints(public APIs)` so I can send `Rest` calls without having problem.

Here is my code:

```
(def handler (-> route.all/routes
                 log-middleware
                 (wrap-defaults site-defaults);;which provides CSRF protection
                 wrap-exceptions
                 wrap-reload
                 wrap-gzip))

(defn start
  [port]
  (jetty/run-jetty handler {:port port}))
```

***P.S: I use Liberator along with Ring***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to *James Reeves*, he has answered this question over [here](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-anti-forgery/pull/14)